# How to remove orig ident. already data normalized, scaled assigned cluster/

Tags: r, rna-seq, scrnaseq, seurat

How to remove orig ident. already data normalized, scaled assigned cluster/ Example, I have 4 sample data. like 1-control, 2- treatment with A, 3- treatment with B, and 4- treatment with C,
I want to remove. I want to remove 3- treatment with B, and want to use all 3 ident for downstream analysis. without doing again rescaling and assigning cluster cell type. is it possible?
if yes please tell Sauret r coding so i can run analysis in R

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add an example of your input data (use the [formatting tools](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and format it as code by selecting the text and pressing the `{}` button) and then show what output you would want from that example so we can understand what you need.

Comment: The answer depends on how your Seurat object has been created and what the metadata looks like, so please heed terdon's request and provide a representative example of your data and the code you have used.

Comment: Can you please add some more filler words into your question? It's very difficult to understand what you're asking in the abbreviated summary format that you've used here.